# How to use ggplot to draw bar colored by different category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as following:

```
       id variable value
1   11149   a      500
2      91   b      1000
3   43233   a      500
4   42499   c      10
5  163993   c      30
```

I would like to draw a bar chart with id as x, sum of value as y, and each bar is fill with different color group by variable.

I wrote code as

```
ggplot(data2,aes(id,value))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat="identity")
```

It does not work well and give a warning as

```
Warning message:
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting `id` to a factor:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(factor(id), value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat="identity")
```